# C# BitConverter to Java

Tags: java, bitconverter

I am trying to port some existing C# code that uses BitConverter to Java. I have found various other threads, but then happened upon a github class that appears to do the trick.  However, the ToUInt16 does not match the output from my C# code. The ToInt16 and ToInt32 appear to be returning the same values.  Can you help me understand what is wrong with this implementation (or possibly what I am doing wrong)?

Code Ref: [Java BitConverter](https://github.com/peace-maker/lysis-java/blob/master/src/lysis/BitConverter.java)

**ToUInt16:**

```
public static int ToUInt16(byte[] bytes, int offset) {
        int result = (int)bytes[offset+1]&0xff;
        result |= ((int)bytes[offset]&0xff) << 8;
        if(Lysis.bDebug)
            System.out.println(result & 0xffff);
        return result & 0xffff;
    }
```

**ToUInt32:**

```
public static long ToUInt32(byte[] bytes, int offset) {
    long result = (int)bytes[offset]&0xff;
    result |= ((int)bytes[offset+1]&0xff) << 8;
    result |= ((int)bytes[offset+2]&0xff) << 16;
    result |= ((int)bytes[offset+3]&0xff) << 24;
    if(Lysis.bDebug)
        System.out.println(result & 0xFFFFFFFFL);
    return result & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
}
```

**MyCode Snippet:**

```
byte[] byteArray = from some byte array
int offset = currentOffset
int msTime = BitConverter.ToUInt16(byteArray, offset)
```

msTime does not match what is coming from C#

**C# Example (string from vendor gets converted from a string using Convert.FromBase64String)**

```
byte[] rawData = Convert.FromBase64String(vendorRawData);
    byte[] sampleDataRaw = rawData;

    Assert.AreEqual(15616, sampleDataRaw.Length);

    //Show byte data for msTime
    Console.WriteLine(sampleDataRaw[7]);
    Console.WriteLine(sampleDataRaw[6]);

    //Show byte data for msTime
    Console.WriteLine(sampleDataRaw[14]);
    Console.WriteLine(sampleDataRaw[13]);

    var msTime = BitConverter.ToUInt16(sampleDataRaw, 6);
    var dmWindow = BitConverter.ToUInt16(sampleDataRaw, 13);
    Assert.AreEqual(399, msTime);
    Assert.AreEqual(10, dmWindow);
```

**C# Console Output for byte values:**

```
1
143
0
10
```

**Groovy Example (string from vendor gets converted from a string using groovy decodeBase64())**

```
    def rawData = vendorRawData.decodeBase64()
    def sampleDataRaw = rawData
    Assert.assertEquals(15616, rawData.length)

    //Show byte data for msTime
    println sampleDataRaw[7]
    println sampleDataRaw[6]

    //Show byte data for dmWindow
    println sampleDataRaw[14]
    println sampleDataRaw[13]

    def msTime = ToUInt16(sampleDataRaw, 6)
    def dmWindow = ToUInt16(sampleDataRaw, 13)
    Assert.assertEquals(399, msTime)
    Assert.assertEquals(10, dmWindow)

**Asserts fail with** 

    399 fro msTime is actually 36609
    10 from dmWindow is actually 2560
```

**Groovy Output from Byte values in println**

```
1
-113
0
10
```

Comment: Can you provide some failing testcases, so we can see what output you expect, and are actually getting, for a given input?

Comment: In case it helps, you may want to consult the .Net implementation which can be found in the reference source https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/bitconverter.cs,567d835b31ee9268,references

Comment: An example would be good.  Also, I'd recommend using `ByteBuffer` for these kinds of conversions.  It can do all this without a library.

Comment: Thanks @pinkfloydx33 I had looked at the docs, but hadn't found the source. I appreciate that.

Comment: Thanks @slim, I had just mocked it up in the thread and didn't think about the static. I tweaked it, but will try to provide an actual sample.

Comment: Thanks @John16384, I will take a look at ByteBuffer as well.

Comment: Just tests along the lines of `assertEquals(1, BitConverter.ToUint16(new byte[] { (byte) 0, (byte) 1 }, 0)` ... with some values that fail. PS you can tell it's mocked up, because there are no semicolons ;)

Comment: Hi @slim, I added output from my .Net and Groovy tests to show where I am getting discrepancies. Thanks!

Comment: @scarpacci `assertEquals(399, BitConvertor.toUInt16((byte) -113, (byte) 1)` would have been better -- the smallest example that shows your problem. But it doesn't really matter any more as you've got a correct answer from @jornVernee

Answer (score 2):

There is a discrepancy between the two methods. The first one `ToUInt16` assumes big-endian byte order. i.e the first byte is the most significant byte.

But `ToUInt32` assumes little-endian byte order (a strange choice). So the first byte is least significant.

A corrected implementation would look like:

```
public static long toUInt32(byte[] bytes, int offset) {
    long result = Byte.toUnsignedLong(bytes[offset+3]);
    result |= Byte.toUnsignedLong(bytes[offset+2]) << 8;
    result |= Byte.toUnsignedLong(bytes[offset+1]) << 16;
    result |= Byte.toUnsignedLong(bytes[offset]) << 24;
    return result;
}
```

Where the array indexing is 'reversed'.

(I also changed the hacky looking bitmasking to clearer calls to `Byte.toUnsignedLong`, which does the same thing.)

Comment: Thanks @Jorn Vernee! What would I need to change with the ToUInt16 implementation, if anything? It is also returning a result that doesn't match.

Comment: @scarpacci I would need to see a [mcve]. in my own testing code `ToUInt16` performs as expected.

Comment: Sounds good. I will work on getting an example. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I added test output so you can see where I am getting discrepancies. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @scarpacci You're printing the output before calling `ToUInt16`, so the problem should lie in the base64 decoding (which I've heard about before).

Comment: @scarpacci Sorry, actually, there might not be any problem. The difference is just that a byte in Java is signed. Otherwise the outputs look the same. The conversion method accounts for that also.

Comment: Hi @Jorn Vernee, what I found after further investigation is that using the ToInt16 gives me results that match my .Net implementation. This seems to coincide with the link https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/bitconverter.cs,567d835b31ee9268,references that pinkfloydx33  provided. I have not verified every field, but of the 10 I did, they all matched.

Answer (score 0):

What I actually found, was that the ToInt16 is actually giving me the results I wanted, not the ToUInt16 in the solution. I have checked quite a few results and they all match the .Net output.

The [link](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/bitconverter.cs,567d835b31ee9268,references) from @pinkfloydx33 where I could see the source code, is actually what led me to try and use ToInt16 instead of ToUInt16.